# Babel 7 does not include Object.entries Core-JS polyfill using @babel/env

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have configured babel to useBuiltIns: "usage" and set the target to not dead and >0.25% of browser but still it is not importing Object.entries polyfill in the webpack build which breaks the code in IE11. So i want to know what wrong i could be doing below is my babel configuration

{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/env",
        {
          "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "corejs": { "version": "3.6.5", "proposals": true }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/react"
    ]

}